# Python - Error when concatenating columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to perform a loop over a set of columns as below:

```
for i in range(len(parent)):
    for j in range(4):
        table.cell(i, j).text = str(locals()["child_" + i + "_" + j])
```

I am getting an error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Error in line `table.cell(i, j).text = str(locals()["child_" + i + "_" + j])`

Comment: Convert the `int` to `str` before concatenating: `table.cell(i, j).text = str(locals()["child_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j)])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
["child_" + i + "_" + j]
```

should be

```
["child_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j)]
```

Convert `int` to `str` before concatenating.